# Get the behavior of System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert() in a Release build?

Tags: c#, assert

I want to detect and report bugs in specific cases, using the same behavior as `Debug.Assert()`, but in a Release build. How can I do that?

Comment: No offense, but how does a "former member of C# team at Microsoft" (your profile description) not know about `Trace.Assert`?

Comment: The list of things I don't know is very, very long.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021538/debug-assert-appears-in-release-mode While the intention is quite the opposite, the answers should give you the clue you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to use `Trace.Assert()`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk4kachs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Use the Trace.Assert method if you want to do assertions in release builds. The Debug.Assert method works only in debug builds.

Comment: Even better than my answer, I did not know about `Trace.Assert`

Answer (score 2):

You can manually add the DEBUG constant while still having Release optimizations enabled.

In the Build tab of your project settings just check the box that enables the DEBUG constant.

[image]

This allows all functions that have [`[ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (like [`Assert()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kssw4w7z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) to still function in your compiled program.

**EDIT:** [Grant's answer is even better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21153277/80274), if possible use `Trace.Assert` instead. That function triggers on if the constant `TRACE` is defined and it is defined by default in Release builds. That will make sure you don't get any unforeseen side effects of enabling any other code that uses `#if DEBUG` or `[ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you turn on Tracing and perform tracing? You can use conditional tracing in Release mode. Also, you can implement some conditionally logging with log4net